# Using unicode / utf-8 in programmers editors

Tags: unicode, utf-8, editor

There are a lot of programmers editors that claim to support unicode / utf-8.  I've tried a number of them (UltraEdit, jedit, emedit) but none of them tell you how to actually enter unicode characters into a file.  Some of them tell you how to change the default file encoding to utf-8 or how to select a font that has good support for utf-8, but not how to enter utf-8 into a file using their editor.

The Go language (and some others) support utf-8 and I like the idea of using the actual utf-8 symbols for variables instead of variables with names like omega.  I haven't found a programmers editor yet that actually allows you to do this, though.

The only editor / word processor that I've found that lets you how to enter unicode is Microsoft Word.  Type the unicode and Alt+X and Word converts it.  To get the Greek letter omega type "03c9" followed by Alt+X.  UltraEdit will let you copy utf-8 from a web page into it, but their docs don't say how to actually enter utf-8 in a file, and their tech. support people don't know either.

This should be simple, but seems to be completely undocumented.  Is there some key combination convention the lets you enter unicode into these editors that supposedly support unicode the way that Ctrl-F is widely used for search?

Thanks.

Comment: "Supporting UTF-8" and "holding your hand for inputting it" are two different things. The OS is typically the one providing input methods for text of various languages.

Comment: When you write "enter Unicode", you seem to mean character entities or escape sequences (depending on the type of content you are writing). But you should be able to input "real" characters directly into any editor with decent Unicode support. (Except that Chinese hanzi and Japanese kanji don't display in jEdit.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like the unicode support in programmers editors (except for some Microsoft products) is mostly read-only.  They can open a file with unicode and display the characters, but typing unicode into a file is a different story.  If you want to enter unicode in a programmers editor you can copy it from somewhere else (a web page or Microsoft Word or Notepad) and paste it into the editor, but the editors make typing unicode difficult or impossible.

UltraEdit tech support referred me to [this web page](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm) which explains a lot.  Unfortunately none of the solutions worked with UltraEdit.

Microsoft Word and Notepad support unicode entry.  Type the unicode value followed by Alt+X and it converts the hexadecimal and displays it.  You can then copy and paste it into UltraEdit or one of the other programmers editors.  As others have mentioned unicode support depends on support within the operating system as well as the editor.

What got me interested in using unicode in source code files is Mark Summerfield's book Programming in Go.  He includes an example .go file that uses unicode.  It would be great to use unicode Greek characters for variable names instead of variables named "omega" or "theta".

Using unicode in source code is a bad idea, however.  Support for unicode in programmers editors is lousy, and developers would have to save or convert their source code files to utf-8 instead of ASCII.  Developer's tools are just not ready to write code in unicode no matter how neat the idea sounds.

Comment: For what it's worth, I can "program in Unicode" using my Japanese input method and/or a keyboard which features "non-ASCII characters" just fine in Sublime Text on OS X. You're over generalizing here.

Comment: UltraEdit supports unicode entry by holding down the ALT key and typing a numeric value on the numeric keypad.  This doesn't support entering hexadecimal values, however.  They've added hexadecimal entry as an enhancement request.

Answer (score 2):

The standard programmer’s editor *vim*(1) supports limited Unicode input even if your operating system should be too broken to do so (are there any such, still?).

Just enter `^VuXXXX`, where `XXXX` represents exactly four hex digits.

That will allow you to enter the ~6% of Unicode allocated to the Basic Multilingual Plane.  The rest are forbidden to you.

This may be fixed in a newer release.

Otherwise, just use your mouse.

Comment: Tried that on vim on Windows and it doesn't work.  Do I need to use any special keys (Ctrl, Alt, ...)?

Comment: Ctrl-V pastes what is in the buffer on windows.

Comment: @DeanSchulze: on Windows use Ctrl-Q, see `:help ctrl-v`.

Comment: @tchrist: non-ancient versions of vim should support `^VUXXXXXXXX`. cf. `:help i_CTRL-V_digit`.

Comment: @ninjalj Ah right.  Lame to have to type all those extra digits though.  That’s why the Java regex syntax went to `\x{XXX}`.

Answer (score 2):

A few techniques I use if an editor is lacking:

1. Use the Windows `charmap.exe` utility to select characters and paste into a document.
2. Install an input method editor (IME) to write in a particular language.
3. [Windows ALT keycodes](http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/accents/codealt.html).

Comment: Especially a Japanese IME can be helpful with its ability to convert to several different candidates. Not sure how well the Windows Japanese IME works in this regard though.

Comment: For example, with the OS X Japanese IME: enter "o-m-e-g-a", hit space a few times → ω. （・ω・）

Answer (score 2):

Better to set your keyboard to generate Unicode characters across all Windows applications than to rely on a single application's custom input feature IMO.

Use the [`EnableHexNumpad` feature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#In_Microsoft_Windows) and you can type any character in the Basic Multilingual Plane using Alt+numbad-plus,hexcode. (May not be of much use on a laptop without a numpad though.)

Or if there are particular characters you want to type a lot, find a keyboard layout that allows you to type them directly. For example [eurokb](http://www.doxdesk.com/software/win/eurokb.html) might cover it, or you can make your own with [MSKLC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but you can type a lot of unicode in GNU Emacs or Vim

- GNU Emacs: `M-x set-input-method RET tex` (or `C-x RET C-\ tex`) will let you type `\omega` to generate ω
- Vim: Vim *digraphs* can generate unicode; `C-k w *` in insert mode gives you ω.

Answer (score 0):

deceze hit the nail on the head. (S)he just didn't elaborate.  bobince gave a bit more.

And I'm hazarding a guess that you're a developer or tester working on L14N or I18N.  I'm also guessing you need to do more than just a few characters here or there, or you'd be satisfied with pasting from another app.  So, I'll share some advice.  (note: here, "you" refers to the next person to look here.  I'm sure the original poster doesn't care anymore by now. :-))

If you're on Windows 10, install an appropriate keyboard driver that lets you input the characters you want into any application.  I'm sure Linux has support for the same sort of thing.

E.g. I'm teaching myself Hindi (हिंदी), so I installed Windows' Hindi (Devanangari) support.  I typed "Hindi", in Hindi using that support, then I switched back to US English to do the rest of this post.  If all you need are accented characters from Western European languages, you can install the INTL English support and type directly in español or français or whatever.

Don't look at entering Unicode characters as entering some sort of special data amidst your English text.  It's just someone else's language.  Use their keyboard.  Type their language.

I'm writing a flashcard app to help my learning.  I'm using the Hindi keyboard support to type characters into Word, WordPad, Excel, and the Visual Studio editor.  And that Hindi keyboard support *works exactly the same way in all of those apps*, as I'd expect it to work in just about any text editor that supports Unicode.  And as you saw above, it also works in a simple text edit control in Chrome.  No copy and paste.  No remembering special codes.  It's as ubiquitous as ctrl-F.